# error incompatible types: Comparable<T> cannot be converted to T

Tags: java

I'm not sure what is going on.
The method works pereclty with an array but if I use a list... well.

I really hope you can help me.

```
public static <T> void ordenaSeleccion(List<? extends Comparable<T>> datos)
{
    Object aux;
    int menor;

    for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
        menor = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < datos.size(); j++) {
            if (datos.get(menor).compareTo(datos.get(j)) > 0) { //error line
                menor = j;
            }
        }

        if (menor != i) {
            aux = datos.get(i);
            datos.set(i, datos.get(menor));
            datos.set(menor, aux);
        }

    }
}
```

this is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`List<? extends Comparable<T>>` only says that the elements of the list can be compared with instances of `T`, not that they are subclasses of `T`. That's why you get your error message.

Could you change your implementation as follows:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void ordenaSeleccion(List<T> datos)
{
    T aux;
    int menor;

    for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
        menor = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < datos.size(); j++) {
            if (datos.get(menor).compareTo(datos.get(j)) > 0) { //error line
                menor = j;
            }
        }

        if (menor != i) {
            aux = datos.get(i);
            datos.set(i, datos.get(menor));
            datos.set(menor, aux);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's assign types to each of these:

```
Comparable<T> m = datos.get(menor);
Comparable<T> mj = datos.get(j);
if ((m).compareTo(mj) > 0) { //error line
```

The `Comparable<T>` interface expects a `T`, not a `Comparable<T>`, as its parameter.

Your signature should instead be:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void ordenaSeleccion(List<T> datos)
```